# вывод Яндекс карты - много городов

Tags: html, yandex-maps-api

Доброго дня, подсобите советом:
на сайте много страниц с разными городами
на каждой странице города нужно выводить карту с центрированием на выбранный город

Знаю, что можно сгенерировать скрипт карты под каждый город, но это неудобно.
Знаю, что можно получить местоположение по IP.

Подскажите, кто с подобным сталкивался, может есть возможность задавать параметры координат в сам div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-то потребуется, код конструкции:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
   var activeItem = $('.main-addresses__item').attr('data-coord');
    activeItem = JSON.parse(activeItem);
  
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('myMap', { 
    center: activeItem, 
    zoom: 11, 
    controls: ['zoomControl'] 
  }); 
 
 
  $('.main-addresses__item').each(function() { 
    var obj = $(this).attr("data-coord"); 
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);
    myMap.geoObjects 
      .add(new ymaps.Placemark(obj, {
        iconCaption: 'Тестовая Метка' 
      }, { 
        preset: 'islands#greenDotIconWithCaption', 
        iconColor: '#ed4543' 
      })); 
   });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://yastatic.net/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU"></script>
<div class="main-addresses__item" data-coord="[55.891586, 38.071433]" id="myMap" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: задавать географические координаты. Например, [Ижевск](https://yandex.kz/maps/-/CBQyjTAjTA) имеет следующие координаты:

> 56.852775, 53.211463

Comment: как задавать координаты я то понимаю, здесь суть вопроса выводить свой скрипт на каждый город или есть еще варианты? не очень хочется делать для 10 городов 10 скриптов яндекс карт

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от архитектуры, подходов  и технологий которые ты используешь. Местоположения лучше узнавай так navigator.geolocation. Создай один скрипт для инициализации карты, пусть карта у тебя будет одна, не надо засирать код. Создай функции js для очистки карты от маркеров, добавления и для центрирования. И все будет збс. 
Если все же хочешь много карт, то ты могешь в див фигачить свои атрибуты как тебе удобно, со своими значениями, и забирать их с помощью например jquery attr. 
Вот например

```
<div id='map' lng='22' lat='88'></div>
```

А так ты получишь эти значения перед инициализацией карты

$('#map').attr('lng')